# Session management in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, session-cookies, next.js

I am using nextjs in my reactjs project. In nextjs the getInitialProps() is called on the serverend for the first page load, and because of that we cannot access the localstorage to get sessions.
How can we manage sessions properly with nextjs.

Comment: Take the advantage of cookie like [this](https://github.com/estrada9166/server-authentication-next.js)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use cookies to store the session.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2252#issuecomment-308238001):

**Client-side**

```js
import jsCookie from 'js-cookie';

const result = await api.login(user, pwd);

if (result.status === 200) {
  jsCookie.set('token', result.token);
}
```

**Server-side**

```js
import jsHttpCookie from 'cookie';

class MyPage extends Component {

  static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    const initProps = {};

    if (req && req.headers) {
      const cookies = req.headers.cookie;

      if (typeof cookies === 'string') {
        const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies);

        initProps.token = cookiesJSON.token;
      }
    }

    return initProps;
  }

}
```

Comment: Seems you have used wrong heading "Server-side", "Client-side"

Comment: No they are the good ones, you can follow the link to have more info.